# Can't build or install eosio.cdt

Tags: eosio.cdt, build, installation

I can't seem to install or build from source following the tutorials on eos.io. Trying to install from package results in a huge list of errors that look like:

```
E: Release 'eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb' for 'sublime-merge' was not found
E: Release 'eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb' for 'mysql-connector-java' was not found
E: Release 'eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb' for 'atom' was not found
E: Release 'eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb' for 'discord' was not found
```

Trying to build form source I get as far as running build.sh but it fails halfway through-

```
-- Setting up Eosio Wasm Toolchain 1.3.2 at 
/home/userabuser/Documents/Programming/oes/projects/contracts/eosio.cdt
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: 
/home/userabuser/Documents/Programming/oes/projects/contracts/eosio.cdt
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Can't find any solutions anywhere. I'm on Debian 8.0 Jessie.

Comment: which linux/macos version you are using ?

Comment: Ah whoops edited, I'm on Debian 8.0 (Jessie)